# why there is difference between psql -version output and the psql version connected to my application? how can I resolve this

Tags: 13.04, ruby, downgrade, postgresql

I am building up a rails application that I cloned from my friend. I am using Ubuntu 13.10, rails 3.2.14. I am using a postgresql database and when I try to run rake db:migrate it gives me some error like this:

PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "json" does not exist
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "filters" ADD COLUMN "search_string" json

I installed pg version :- 9.3.1

running rails db output is :-psql (9.3.1, server 9.1.10)

running select version(); :-PostgreSQL 9.1.10 on i686-pc-linux-gnu

Why is it showing psql -version different from the version connected to my database??

My friend is working on 9.2.4 I don't know why this error is occurring, I tried several times to downgrade using purge or remove commands to remove 9.3.1 all goes well but when I check psql --version it again shows me 9.3.1 . Any solution ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you probably have different client and server version packages installed.  First, I'd check what packages you have installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep postgresql
```

Then install the 9.3 server package if you don't already have it.

If you already have it, check what clusters you have running:

```
pg_lsclusters
```

If you don't already have a 9.3 cluster, make one (`pg_createcluster`).  If you do, note the port number and make sure you connect to that one.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres 9.2 is not packaged for Ubuntu 13.10, but 9.1 is. Try to do it like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql*

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
```

Comment: Hey Luis I run the first command it gives me output:-           E: Unable to locate package postgresql-8.4.9.tar.gz
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-8.4.9.tar.gz'
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-8.4.9.tar.gz.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-8.4.9.tar.gz.1'

Comment: If I am at my home path then it gives me this error :-          E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.2.4
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.2.4'
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.2.4.tar.gz
In my project 8.4.9 file was present I removed that using rm and now it is giving me :- zsh: no matches found: postgresql*

Comment: If I am running :- sudo apt-get autoremove                                   Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
                                                                 After this when I am running sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-9.1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.

Comment: Then it seems you have postgres 9.1 already installed. What version are you getting inside psql?